# Spivak Ed.1 Chapter 22 Problem 1 (xi)

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

The problem asks to determine whether
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log \ n)^n}
$$
converges or not. The answer states that it converges because $ \frac{1}{(\log \ n)^n} \lt \frac{1}{2^n} \text{ for }  n \gt 9$.

Could anybody explain why Professor Spivak affirms that?

Comment: You can also use the [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) on it.

Comment: I did not realize, thank you! However, I was asking why does the answer points out that comparison.

Comment: Surely you can find a value of $n$ for which $2 < \log n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to check that $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log  n)^n}$$ is summable or not.  Let be $a_n=\frac{1}{(\log n)^n}$. Being $2<e<3$, then $\log n >2$ when ever $n>9$. This gives:

$$\frac{1}{(\log n)^n}<\frac{1}{2^n}\, \text{ for all } n>9. $$ Since
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}$$ is convergent and $\frac{1}{(\log n)^n}>0$ for all $n\geq 2$, so by comparison test of series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log  n)^n}$$ is convergent.